# How can I instances of an account when more than one ref is used for seeds?

Tags: anchor, pda, bump

In order to create history and statistics, I'm struggling to figure out the best way to implement a lookup system. I'm building a game, and right now, my init for the entrant account looks like this:

```
    #[account(
        init, 
        payer = player,
        seeds = [b"entrant", player.key().as_ref(), round.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        space = 8 + Entrant::MAXIMUM_SIZE)
    ]
    pub entrant: Account<'info, Entrant>,
```

Since a player can enter more than one round, I'm using both the player key and the round key as the seeds.

However, given the player, I want to be able to somehow lookup all the rounds the player has ever played. I don't want to keep in in one account, as this game can have a lot of rounds and I don't want to run out space.

What would be the best practice in dealing with a situation like this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use:

`seeds = [b"entrant", game.key().as_ref(), player.key().as_ref(), round.key().as_ref()]`

And pass the relevant round to the `program`.

The client can search via `getProgramAccounts` for the `player`/`game` combo.

Comment: Thanks! I think I was a little unclear. There is only one game, as a one game = one round, so there is no "game" account.

Comment: The issue is, that you need to pass the `program` all accounts for the transaction. So an on-chain lookup doesn't help much. Since you can just supply a pointer to it an use that. Unless you store a blob of data on-chain which is expensive and limited.

Comment: Hmm.  That's tough. How would you handle a game that has more players than can fit in an account.  Let's say 2000 people participate in a game

Comment: Do you need all 2000 players info in each txn?

Comment: I was able to figure out a different structure for this in the contract where I just check to see individually if the user won each round, and can use the getProgramAccounts on the client. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options:

- iterate through all the possible combinations of seeds for a user.  If you know that the current max round is 2000, you can try all possible 2000 entrant addresses and fetch the account there.  For huge numbers, this will be tricky.
- store the player address in the entrant account, and then do a `get_program_accounts` with the correct offsets for the entrant account type and the user's address